# Accessing a react state created in one component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks

thanks for taking the time to help me with this challenge.
I'm working on a project where I need the state **goodData** created in one component **AddProduct** to be accessed in another component **ActionBox** in the same jsx file. I tried using use-between but it still doesn't work. Also If they are in different files how do I get it done?
Below is the code.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import {IoMdAdd, IoIosListBox} from 'react-icons/io'
import {MdClear} from 'react-icons/md'
import {AiOutlineMinusSquare} from 'react-icons/ai'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import  {AiFillCloseCircle} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {useBetween} from 'use-between'
import { goods } from '../dataArray'

const AddProduct = () => {
    const [presentDate, setPresentDate] = useState('')
    const [goodData, setGoodData] = useState({modDate: '',product: '', quantity: '', unitPrice: '', totPrice: ''})
    const [dropStockList, setDropStockList] = useState(true)
    const [stock, setStock] = useState([])
    const [shop, setShop] = useState([])
    const [display, setDisplay]  = useState(true)
    const [actionBtn, setActionBtn] = useState(true)

    useEffect(()=>{
        let date = new Date()
        let day = date.getUTCDay()
        let month = date.getUTCMonth()
        let year = date.getUTCFullYear()
        let newDate = day+'/'+month+'/'+year
        setPresentDate(newDate)
        let list;
        if (localStorage.getItem('shopDB') !== null) {
            list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shopDB')).warehouse
            setStock(list)
        }
    },[])

    function handleNewStock(data) {
        let shopDB;
        if (localStorage.getItem('shopDB') !== null) {
            shopDB = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shopDB'))
            shopDB.warehouse.push(data)
        }
        else{
            // shit then
        }
        localStorage.setItem('shopDB', JSON.stringify(shopDB))
    }

    function handleChange(e) {
        let name = e.target.name
        let value = e.target.value
        setGoodData({...goodData, [name]:value})
    }
    
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        if (goodData.product && goodData.quantity && goodData.unitPrice ) {
            goodData.totPrice = goodData.quantity * goodData.unitPrice
            goodData.modDate = presentDate
            setStock([...stock, goodData]) 
            handleNewStock(goodData)
            setGoodData({modDate: '', product:'', quantity: '', totPrice: '', unitPrice: ''})
            
        }else{
            // highlight unfilled field
        }
    }
    function handleCheck() {
        if (display) {
            setDisplay(false)
        }
        if (!display){
            setDisplay(true)
        }
    }
    
    function handleStockList() {
        if (dropStockList) {
            setDropStockList(false)
            
        }
        if (!dropStockList) {
            setDropStockList(true)
        }
    }
    function handleBlurClose() {
        // setDisplay(false)
    }
    return (
    <>
    {display && <section className="add-stock-cont" >
        <div className="addition" onBlur={handleBlurClose}>
            <div className="nav">
                <section className="title">
                    <h2>Add New Product</h2>
                </section>
                <span id="close-icon" onClick={handleCheck}>
                    <AiFillCloseCircle />
                </span>
            </div>

            {display && 
            <form className="add-area">
                <section className="top">

                    <section className = "product form-group" >
                        <label htmlFor = "product" > Product </label> 
                        <input type = "text"
                        name = "product"
                        id = "product"
                        placeholder = 'Semovita...'
                        onChange = { handleChange }
                        value = { goodData.product }/> 
                    </section>

                    <section className = "quantity form-group" >
                        <label htmlFor = "quantity" > Quantity </label> 
                        <input type = "number"
                        name = "quantity"
                        id = "quantity"
                        placeholder = '0'
                        onChange = { handleChange }
                        value = { goodData.quantity }/> 
                    </section>

                    
                    <section className = "unitPrice form-group" >
                        <label htmlFor = "unitPrice" > Unit Price </label> 
                        <input type = "number"
                        name = "unitPrice"
                        id = "unitPrice"
                        placeholder = '0'
                        onChange = { handleChange }
                        value = { goodData.unitPrice }/> 
                    </section>

                    <article className="totPrice">
                        <h4>{goodData.totPrice}</h4>
                    </article>

                </section>
                <section className="buttons">
                    {actionBtn &&<button className="unClear-btn add-btn" type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>
                        <span id='icon'><IoMdAdd /> </span> Add
                    </button>}
                    {!actionBtn && <button className="warning-color unClear-btn" id="update-btn">Update</button>}
                    <button className="unClear-btn clear-btn"><span id="icon"><MdClear /> </span> Clear</button>
                        {!actionBtn && <button className="unClear-btn " id="delete-btn">Delete</button>}
                </section>
            </form>}
            <section className="stock-list">
                <div className="menu-bar" onClick={handleStockList}>
                    {dropStockList ?  <span id="icon"><AiOutlineMinusSquare /> </span> : <span id="icon"><IoIosListBox/> </span>  }
                </div>
                {dropStockList &&  
                <section className="table-holder">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date Mod.</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Unit Price</th>
                                <th>Total Price</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            
                                {stock.map((data, index)=>{
                                    const {product, quantity, unitPrice, totPrice, modDate} = data

                                    return(
                                        <tr key={index}>
                                            <td>{modDate}</td>
                                            <td>{product}</td>
                                            <td>{quantity}</td>
                                            <td>{unitPrice}</td>
                                            <td>{totPrice}</td>
                                            <td><ActionBox index={index} product={data.product} quantity={data.quantity} unitPrice={data.unitPrice} totPrice={data.totPrice} goodDatad={goodData}/> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                })}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                
                </section>
                }
            </section>
        </div> 
    </section>}
   </> )
}

export default AddProduct

const useSharedState = () => useBetween(AddProduct)

const ActionBox = (index, unitPrice, product, quantity, totPrice, goodDatad)=>{
    const [dropDown,  setDropDown] = useState(false)
    const {goodData} = useSharedState();

    function handleEdit() {
        console.log(index);
        console.log('printing...', goodData);
        let shopDB;
        if (localStorage.getItem('shopDB') !== null) {
            shopDB = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shopDB')).warehouse
            console.log('the necessary info',shopDB.at(index.index));
        }else{
            console.log('You are on your own lol...');
        }
    }

    return(
        <button className="unClear-btn" onClick={handleEdit}>
            action
        </button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be to hold the *state* in a *parent component* and manipulating it as a props function from the **AddProduct** component.
Please check this article.
It has a working example.
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html